# example of Angular routed module

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular5

I would like to have an example of **routed modules** described in the following link:
https://angular.io/guide/module-types

> Routed feature modules are domain feature modules whose top components
>   are the targets of router navigation routes. All lazy-loaded modules
>   are routed feature modules by definition. Routed feature modules don’t
>   export anything because their components never appear in the template
>   of an external component. A lazy-loaded routed feature module should
>   not be imported by any module. Doing so would trigger an eager load,
>   defeating the purpose of lazy loading.That means you won’t see them
>   mentioned among the AppModule imports. An eager loaded routed feature
>   module must be imported by another module so that the compiler learns
>   about its components. Routed feature modules rarely have providers for
>   reasons explained in Lazy Loading Feature Modules. When they do, the
>   lifetime of the provided services should be the same as the lifetime
>   of the module. Don't provide application-wide singleton services in a
>   routed feature module or in a module that the routed module imports.

I don't seem to find an example on the routing page of angular.io.

Answer (score 1):

As the description clearly states, a routed module is a lazy loaded feature module.

Here's the Wiki Page for lazy loaded modules.

https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules